# Automated UI Testing on Android: preconditions and user session?

Tags: android, automated-tests, ui-testing

I am working on automated UI Testing for an Android project I am working on. I chose Espresso to write the tests. I need to write a UI test that requires the user to be logged in. How can I do this?

I have seen implementations of the testPrecionditions method, but they seem too basic and only take care of checking the state of the views.

I have also found some examples of Calabash tests, but they execute the entire login routine from scratch before running the desired test. I believe I can replicate that behaviour by writing extremely long tests, but it does not seem right to me.

The third alternative, which I am unfamiliar with, is to use mock objects to simulate the user session by returning mock data. However, I am not sure this is the right approach for Automated UI Testing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally followed the approach described [here](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2010/06/29/android-functional-testing-vs-dependency-injection/).

I have a class encapsulates all the API calls, so I just created a Mock class to replace it during the tests. Tests run faster now and the outcome is more predictable.

This is an example:

```
public class MyActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

    public DeregisterDeviceActivityTest() {
        super(DeregisterDeviceActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        // Obtain instance of my mock API wrapper.
        IAPIWrapper api = MockAPIWrapper.getInstance(getInstrumentation().getContext()); 

        // Replace application's wrapper.
        MyApplication.setAPIWrapper(api);

        // Start activity.
        getActivity();
    }

    ...

}
```

Notice I used the instrumentation context to instantiate the mock object. That is because I need to access resources (in this case json files with response samples) that are part of the test project. If I used the activity context I would not be able to access them.